# How to append lists of list into one list

Tags: python, list

Mylists = [['A B','A B C','A B C D'],['C','D E F','A B']]

How can I get a list like: myli = [['A','B','A','B','C','A','B','C','D'],['C','D','E','F','A','B']]

Here is my code:

```
x = []
myli = []

for item in Mylists:
    for i in range(len(item)):
        x.extend(item[i].split())
    myli.append(x)
```

Comment: you need to initialize x inside the outer forloop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize x inside the outer forloop.

Your code

```
Mylists = [['A B','A B C','A B C D'],['C','D E F','A B']]
x = []
myli = []

for item in Mylists:
    for i in range(len(item)):
        # BUG: since x is not reinitialized, it contains the same old
        # memory address that was appended to myli
        # extending x means you are modifying the x that you previously appended to myli
        # infact, every appended x is the same x !
        x.extend(item[i].split())

    # appending the same old x, which will inevitably be modified
    # in the next iteration
    myli.append(x)
```

Correction

```
Mylists = [['A B','A B C','A B C D'],['C','D E F','A B']]
myli = []

for item in Mylists:
    x = [] # reinitialize x
    for i in range(len(item)):
        x.extend(item[i].split())
    myli.append(x)
```

Comment: Thanks. can you explain why do I need to reinitialize x in the outer loop? to empty the x every time?

Comment: @Fox added an explanation as well. let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for help, that makes sense.

Comment: @Fox no problem. mark it if you feel it has answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `mylist` is a list of lists of strings where words are separated by spaces:

```
ml = [['A B','A B C','A B C D'],['C','D E F','A B']]
l = []
for inner in ml:
    newinner = []
    for innerstr in inner:
       for word in innerstr.split(' ')
                newinner.append(word)
    l.append(newinner)
```